# Objective-C. Why Segue push a new viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I Have 2 views:

1. ViewController
2. TableViewController

When I'm in tableViewController I need the Segue to lead me back to the previous view, But it keeps creating a new copy of ViewController.

I need the Segue return me to the last view with no cloning.

[image]

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSString *identifire = [sender text];
    ViewController* vc = (ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    [vc view];
    [vc hideElements:identifire];
}
```

Comment: Have you used unwind segue for that?

Comment: You need to use unwind segue or programatically pop the view controller from navigation stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a regular segue, then a new instance of the viewcontroller will be created. It doesn't matter that the target viewcontroller is placed before your tableviewcontroller in the Storyboard.

You should use an unwind segue instead. Or just pop back to the previous viewcontroller.

Comment: unwind segue is the correct answer, this video discribs it well
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akmPXZ4hDuU

Answer (score 1):

In your `TableViewController` you need to pop back to previous view controller.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

The segue will always create a new view controller and push it on the top os navigation stack in your case. You can use `unwind segue` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
```